# Reported speech

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I want to know the following sentence 
Wrong : “He said that all students should focus during the lesson so they ***would not*** get hurt.” 
Right :  “He said that all students should focus during the lesson so they ***will not***  get hurt.” 
Why is it will not but not would not?

Comment: How is it related to **_math_**.stackexchange.com? Try asking at https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Better suited for https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't particularly math related, but saying **would not** may imply a hypothetical situation. It is like saying if you don't pay attention you may get hurt but it isn't certain. Saying **will not** implies that if you do not pay attention to the lesson it is certain you will get hurt and regret it. I'm by no means an English professor, just my thought, definitely ask on: https://english.stackexchange.com/

Cheers!